# Cant use a php variable to determinate the min of a datatime input?

Tags: php, html

i have a input of type datetime-local in html, and the min should be a data object with php, and i cant see why its not working, the html with the php script inside is:

```
<input name="fechalimite" min="<?php    
                    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
                    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ;

                    echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime(' +20 minutes',strtotime($now)));

    ?>" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fechalimite">
```

the min should be the now data of new york +20m but is not working

Comment: What do you see instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working" or "is not working"?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I would recommend separating your HTML from your PHP logic. It's a little out of scope from your question, but it will make things *much* easier to read.

Using the following code you provided I can get what time it will be in 20 min (as you specified in your question):

```
<?php    

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

$now = date("2018-07-06 16:25:02");
$diff = "+20 minutes";
$then = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($diff, strtotime($now)));

echo "Now: " . $now . "\n";
echo "Then: " . $then . "\n";

// Output 
// Now: 2018-07-06 16:25:02
// Then: 2018-07-06 16:45:02
```

Now implement this in your HTML:

```
<input name="fechalimite" min="<?php echo $then ?>" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fechalimite">
```

You will notice in your browser, this will render:

```
<input name="fechalimite" min="2018-07-06 16:45:02" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fechalimite">
```

You cannot use a "Data object with PHP" as you described in your question, because in your situation PHP just renders strings of data/markup to the browser. You need to output a date string (like you and I have above) and digest that through JavaScript if you want to do any validation tasks with user inputs/interactions/events.

The JavaScript information is out of the scope of your question, but you can read about the `Date` Object/Class in JavaScript here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Use the date format `Y-m-d\TH:i` like so:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ;
$min = date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime('+20 minutes', strtotime($now)));
?>
<input name="fechalimite" min="<?php echo $min; ?>" value="<?php echo $min; ?>" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fechalimite" />
```